# Trying to add LinuxDiagnostic Azure VM Extension through terraform and getting errors

Tags: azure, terraform

I am trying to get the LinuxDiagnostic extension to add via terraform.

The VM is:

```
azure_image_publisher = "Redhat"
azure_image_offer     = "RHEL"
azure_image_sku       = "7.8"
```

My deploy looks like this:

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "diagnostics_linux" {
  count                      = local.is_windows == true ? 0 : 1
  name                       = "LinuxDiagnostic"
  virtual_machine_id         =  azurerm_virtual_machine.main.id
  publisher                  = "Microsoft.Azure.Diagnostics"
  type                       = "LinuxDiagnostic"
  type_handler_version       = "3.0"
  auto_upgrade_minor_version = "true"

  settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
        "storageAccount": "${var.stackSettings.azurerm_storage_account.name}",
        "ladCfg": {
                        "diagnosticMonitorConfiguration": {
                            "eventVolume": "Medium",
                            "metrics": {
                                "metricAggregation": [
                                    {
                                        "scheduledTransferPeriod": "PT1M"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "scheduledTransferPeriod": "PT1H"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "resourceId": "/subscriptions/${var.stackSettings.azure_subscription_id}/resourceGroups/${var.stackSettings.azurerm_resource_group}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/${azurerm_virtual_machine.main.id}"
                            },
                            "syslogEvents": { /** list of syslogs **/},
                            "performanceCounters": {/** list of perf counters **/}
                        },
                        "sampleRateInSeconds": 15
                    }
    }
    SETTINGS

  protected_settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
        "storageAccountName": "${var.stackSettings.azurerm_storage_account.name}",
        "storageAccountKey":  "${var.stackSettings.azurerm_storage_account.primary_access_key}",
        "storageAccountEndPoint": "https://core.windows.net"
    }
    SETTINGS

  depends_on = [azurerm_virtual_machine.main]
}
```

Every time I attempt to apply via terraform I receive the error:

```
Error: Code="VMExtensionProvisioningError" Message="VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'LinuxDiagnostic'. Error message: \"Extension operation Enable failed:'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_fluentd_syslog_src_config'\"\r\n\r\nMore information on troubleshooting is available at https://aka.ms/VMExtensionLinuxDiagnosticsTroubleshoot "

  on ..\..\..\..\modules\Azure-Server\v1\main.tf line 284, in resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "diagnostics_linux":
 284: resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "diagnostics_linux" {
```

My windows diagnostic extension works fine and I took the JSON directly from a working deploy through the portal.

Looking for assistance as to what I could be missing.
Or if someone has the XML LAD version, I would try that too (cannot find it anywhere).

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Full working solution (including getting the pesky SAS Token and reading from json files instead of giant terrform blocks!)
Terraform Config:

```
/**
Linux Diagnostic Agent
The linux diagnostic agent is rather complicated to get working.
You need:
1. A static timestamp for start/expiry time
2. A SAS token from the storage account with custom permissions
3. Importing multiple large jsons with custom cleanup
This is taken care of for everything below
**/


//== Provider used to store timestamp SAS token lifetime ==//
provider "time" {
  version = "~> 0.4"
}

//== Store 10 years in the future ==//
resource "time_offset" "linux_oms_sas_expiry" {
  count = local.is_windows == true ? 0 : 1
  offset_years = 10
}

//== Store (now - 10) days to ensure we have valid SAS ==//
resource "time_offset" "linux_oms_sas_start" {
  count = local.is_windows == true ? 0 : 1
  offset_days = -10
}

//== SAS Token required for Diagnostic Extension ==//
/**
The permissions are based on the linux powershell sas creation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/diagnostics-linux
**/
data "azurerm_storage_account_sas" "linux_oms" {
  count = local.is_windows == true ? 0 : 1
  connection_string = var.stackSettings.azurerm_storage_account.primary_connection_string
  https_only        = true

  resource_types {
    service   = true
    container = true
    object    = true
  }

  services {
    blob  = true
    table = true
    queue = false
    file = false
  }

  start  = time_offset.linux_oms_sas_start[0].rfc3339
  expiry = time_offset.linux_oms_sas_expiry[0].rfc3339

  permissions {
    read    = true
    write   = true
    delete  = true
    list    = true
    add     = true
    create  = true
    update  = true
    process = true
  }
}

//=== Install Diagnostic Extension ===//
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "diagnostics_linux" {
  count                      = local.is_windows == true ? 0 : 1
  name                       = "LinuxDiagnostic"
  virtual_machine_id         =  azurerm_virtual_machine.main.id
  publisher                  = "Microsoft.Azure.Diagnostics"
  type                       = "LinuxDiagnostic"
  type_handler_version       = "3.0"
  auto_upgrade_minor_version = "true"

  settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
      "StorageAccount": "${var.stackSettings.azurerm_storage_account.name}",
      "ladCfg": {
          "diagnosticMonitorConfiguration": {
                "eventVolume": "Medium", 
                "metrics": {
                     "metricAggregation": [
                        {
                            "scheduledTransferPeriod": "PT1H"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "scheduledTransferPeriod": "PT1M"
                        }
                    ], 
                    "resourceId": "${azurerm_virtual_machine.main.id}"
                },
                "performanceCounters": ${file("${path.module}/azure_jsons/azure_extension_diagnostics_linux_performancecounters.json")},
                "syslogEvents": ${file("${path.module}/azure_jsons/azure_extension_diagnostics_linux_syslogevents.json")}
          }, 
          "sampleRateInSeconds": 15
      }
    }
  SETTINGS

  protected_settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
        "storageAccountName": "${var.stackSettings.azurerm_storage_account.name}",
        "storageAccountSasToken": "${data.azurerm_storage_account_sas.linux_oms[0].sas}",
        "storageAccountEndPoint": "https://core.windows.net",
         "sinksConfig":  {
              "sink": [
                {
                    "name": "SyslogJsonBlob",
                    "type": "JsonBlob"
                },
                {
                    "name": "LinuxCpuJsonBlob",
                    "type": "JsonBlob"
                }
              ]
        }
    }
    SETTINGS

  depends_on = [azurerm_virtual_machine.main]
}
```

azure_extension_diagnostics_linux_performancecounters.json :

```
{
    "performanceCounterConfiguration": [
        {
            "annotation": [
                {
                    "displayName": "Disk read guest OS",
                    "locale": "en-us"
                }
            ],
            "class": "disk",
            "condition": "IsAggregate=TRUE",
            "counter": "readbytespersecond",
            "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/disk/readbytespersecond",
            "type": "builtin",
            "unit": "BytesPerSecond"
        },
        {
            "annotation": [
                {
                    "displayName": "Disk writes",
                    "locale": "en-us"
                }
            ],
            "class": "disk",
            "condition": "IsAggregate=TRUE",
            "counter": "writespersecond",
            "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/disk/writespersecond",
            "type": "builtin",
            "unit": "CountPerSecond"
        },
        {
            "annotation": [
                {
                    "displayName": "Disk transfer time",
                    "locale": "en-us"
                }
            ],
            "class": "disk",
            "condition": "IsAggregate=TRUE",
            "counter": "averagetransfertime",
            "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/disk/averagetransfertime",
            "type": "builtin",
            "unit": "Seconds"
        },
        {
            "annotation": [
                {
                    "displayName": "Disk transfers",
                    "locale": "en-us"
                }
            ],
            "class": "disk",
            "condition": "IsAggregate=TRUE",
            "counter": "transferspersecond",
            "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/disk/transferspersecond",
            "type": "builtin",
            "unit": "CountPerSecond"
        },
        {
            "annotation": [
                {
                    "displayName": "Disk write guest OS",
                    "locale": "en-us"
                }
            ],
            "class": "disk",
            "condition": "IsAggregate=TRUE",
            "counter": "writebytespersecond",
            "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/disk/writebytespersecond",
            "type": "builtin",
            "unit": "BytesPerSecond"
        },
        {
            "annotation": [
                {
                    "displayName": "Disk read time",
                    "locale": "en-us"
                }
            ],
            "class": "disk",
            "condition": "IsAggregate=TRUE",
            "counter": "averagereadtime",
            "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/disk/averagereadtime",
            "type": "builtin",
            "unit": "Seconds"
        },
        {
            "annotation": [
                {
                    "displayName": "Disk write time",
                    "locale": "en-us"
                }
            ],
            "class": "disk",
            "condition": "IsAggregate=TRUE",
            "counter": "averagewritetime",
            "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/disk/averagewritetime",
            "type": "builtin",
            "unit": "Seconds"
        },
        {
            "annotation": [
                {
                    "displayName": "Disk total bytes",
                    "locale": "en-us"
                }
            ],
            "class": "disk",
            "condition": "IsAggregate=TRUE",
            "counter": "bytespersecond",
            "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/disk/bytespersecond",
            "type": "builtin",
            "unit": "BytesPerSecond"
        },
        {
            "annotation": [
                {
                    "displayName": "Disk reads",
                    "locale": "en-us"
                }
            ],
            "class": "disk",
            "condition": "IsAggregate=TRUE",
            "counter": "readspersecond",
            "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/disk/readspersecond",
            "type": "builtin",
            "unit": "CountPerSecond"
        },
        {
            "annotation": [
                {
                    "displayName": "Disk queue length",
                    "locale": "en-us"
                }
            ],
            "class": "disk",
            "condition": "IsAggregate=TRUE",
            "counter": "averagediskqueuelength",
            "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/disk/averagediskqueuelength",
            "type": "builtin",
            "unit": "Count"
        },
        {
            "annotation": [
                {
                    "displayName": "Network in guest OS",
                    "locale": "en-us"
                }
            ],
            "class": "network",
            "counter": "bytesreceived",
            "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/network/bytesreceived",
            "type": "builtin",
            "unit": "Bytes"
        },
        {
            "annotation": [
                {
                    "displayName": "Network total bytes",
                    "locale": "en-us"
                }
            ],
            "class": "network",
            "counter": "bytestotal",
            "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/network/bytestotal",
            "type": "builtin",
            "unit": "Bytes"
        },
        {
            "annotation": [
                {
                    "displayName": "Network out guest OS",
                    "locale": "en-us"
                }
            ],
            "class": "network",
            "counter": "bytestransmitted",
            "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/network/bytestransmitted",
            "type": "builtin",
            "unit": "Bytes"
        },
        {
            "annotation": [
                {
                    "displayName": "Network collisions",
                    "locale": "en-us"
                }
            ],
            "class": "network",
            "counter": "totalcollisions",
            "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/network/totalcollisions",
            "type": "builtin",
            "unit": "Count"
        },
        {
            "annotation": [
                {
                    "displayName": "Packets received errors",
                    "locale": "en-us"
                }
            ],
            "class": "network",
            "counter": "totalrxerrors",
            "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/network/totalrxerrors",
            "type": "builtin",
            "unit": "Count"
        },
        {
            "annotation": [
                {
                    "displayName": "Packets sent",
                    "locale": "en-us"
                }
            ],
            "class": "network",
            "counter": "packetstransmitted",
            "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/network/packetstransmitted",
            "type": "builtin",
            "unit": "Count"
        },
        {
            "annotation": [
                {
                    "displayName": "Packets received",
                    "locale": "en-us"
                }
            ],
            "class": "network",
            "counter": "packetsreceived",
            "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/network/packetsreceived",
            "type": "builtin",
            "unit": "Count"
        },
        {
            "annotation": [
                {
                    "displayName": "Packets sent errors",
                    "locale": "en-us"
                }
            ],
            "class": "network",
            "counter": "totaltxerrors",
            "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/network/totaltxerrors",
            "type": "builtin",
            "unit": "Count"
        },
        {
            "annotation": [
                {
                    "displayName": "Filesystem transfers/sec",
                    "locale": "en-us"
                }
            ],
            "class": "filesystem",
            "condition": "IsAggregate=TRUE",
            "counter": "transferspersecond",
            "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/filesystem/transferspersecond",
            "type": "builtin",
            "unit": "CountPerSecond"
        },
        {
            "annotation": [
                {
                    "displayName": "Filesystem % free space",
                    "locale": "en-us"
                }
            ],
            "class": "filesystem",
            "condition": "IsAggregate=TRUE",
            "counter": "percentfreespace",
            "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/filesystem/percentfreespace",
            "type": "builtin",
            "unit": "Percent"
        },
        {
            "annotation": [
                {
                    "displayName": "Filesystem % used space",
                    "locale": "en-us"
                }
            ],
            "class": "filesystem",
            "condition": "IsAggregate=TRUE",
            "counter": "percentusedspace",
            "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/filesystem/percentusedspace",
            "type": "builtin",
            "unit": "Percent"
        },
        {
            "annotation": [
                {
                    "displayName": "Filesystem used space",
                    "locale": "en-us"
                }
            ],
            "class": "filesystem",
            "condition": "IsAggregate=TRUE",
            "counter": "usedspace",
            "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/filesystem/usedspace",
            "type": "builtin",
            "unit": "Bytes"
        },
        {
            "annotation": [
                {
                    "displayName": "Filesystem read bytes/sec",
                    "locale": "en-us"
                }
            ],
            "class": "filesystem",
            "condition": "IsAggregate=TRUE",
            "counter": "bytesreadpersecond",
            "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/filesystem/bytesreadpersecond",
            "type": "builtin",
            "unit": "CountPerSecond"
        },
        {
            "annotation": [
                {
                    "displayName": "Filesystem free space",
                    "locale": "en-us"
                }
            ],
            "class": "filesystem",
            "condition": "IsAggregate=TRUE",
            "counter": "freespace",
            "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/filesystem/freespace",
            "type": "builtin",
            "unit": "Bytes"
        },
        {
            "annotation": [
                {
                    "displayName": "Filesystem % free inodes",
                    "locale": "en-us"
                }
            ],
            "class": "filesystem",
            "condition": "IsAggregate=TRUE",
            "counter": "percentfreeinodes",
            "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/filesystem/percentfreeinodes",
            "type": "builtin",
            "unit": "Percent"
        },
        {
            "annotation": [
                {
                    "displayName": "Filesystem bytes/sec",
                    "locale": "en-us"
                }
            ],
            "class": "filesystem",
            "condition": "IsAggregate=TRUE",
            "counter": "bytespersecond",
            "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/filesystem/bytespersecond",
            "type": "builtin",
            "unit": "BytesPerSecond"
        },
        {
            "annotation": [
                {
                    "displayName": "Filesystem reads/sec",
                    "locale": "en-us"
                }
            ],
            "class": "filesystem",
            "condition": "IsAggregate=TRUE",
            "counter": "readspersecond",
            "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/filesystem/readspersecond",
            "type": "builtin",
            "unit": "CountPerSecond"
        },
        {
            "annotation": [
                {
                    "displayName": "Filesystem write bytes/sec",
                    "locale": "en-us"
                }
            ],
            "class": "filesystem",
            "condition": "IsAggregate=TRUE",
            "counter": "byteswrittenpersecond",
            "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/filesystem/byteswrittenpersecond",
            "type": "builtin",
            "unit": "CountPerSecond"
        },
        {
            "annotation": [
                {
                    "displayName": "Filesystem writes/sec",
                    "locale": "en-us"
                }
            ],
            "class": "filesystem",
            "condition": "IsAggregate=TRUE",
            "counter": "writespersecond",
            "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/filesystem/writespersecond",
            "type": "builtin",
            "unit": "CountPerSecond"
        },
        {
            "annotation": [
                {
                    "displayName": "Filesystem % used inodes",
                    "locale": "en-us"
                }
            ],
            "class": "filesystem",
            "condition": "IsAggregate=TRUE",
            "counter": "percentusedinodes",
            "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/filesystem/percentusedinodes",
            "type": "builtin",
            "unit": "Percent"
        },
        {
            "annotation": [
                {
                    "displayName": "CPU IO wait time",
                    "locale": "en-us"
                }
            ],
            "class": "processor",
            "condition": "IsAggregate=TRUE",
            "counter": "percentiowaittime",
            "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/processor/percentiowaittime",
            "type": "builtin",
            "unit": "Percent"
        },
        {
            "annotation": [
                {
                    "displayName": "CPU user time",
                    "locale": "en-us"
                }
            ],
            "class": "processor",
            "condition": "IsAggregate=TRUE",
            "counter": "percentusertime",
            "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/processor/percentusertime",
            "type": "builtin",
            "unit": "Percent"
        },
        {
            "annotation": [
                {
                    "displayName": "CPU nice time",
                    "locale": "en-us"
                }
            ],
            "class": "processor",
            "condition": "IsAggregate=TRUE",
            "counter": "percentnicetime",
            "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/processor/percentnicetime",
            "type": "builtin",
            "unit": "Percent"
        },
        {
            "annotation": [
                {
                    "displayName": "CPU percentage guest OS",
                    "locale": "en-us"
                }
            ],
            "class": "processor",
            "condition": "IsAggregate=TRUE",
            "counter": "percentprocessortime",
            "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/processor/percentprocessortime",
            "type": "builtin",
            "unit": "Percent"
        },
        {
            "annotation": [
                {
                    "displayName": "CPU interrupt time",
                    "locale": "en-us"
                }
            ],
            "class": "processor",
            "condition": "IsAggregate=TRUE",
            "counter": "percentinterrupttime",
            "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/processor/percentinterrupttime",
            "type": "builtin",
            "unit": "Percent"
        },
        {
            "annotation": [
                {
                    "displayName": "CPU idle time",
                    "locale": "en-us"
                }
            ],
            "class": "processor",
            "condition": "IsAggregate=TRUE",
            "counter": "percentidletime",
            "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/processor/percentidletime",
            "type": "builtin",
            "unit": "Percent"
        },
        {
            "annotation": [
                {
                    "displayName": "CPU privileged time",
                    "locale": "en-us"
                }
            ],
            "class": "processor",
            "condition": "IsAggregate=TRUE",
            "counter": "percentprivilegedtime",
            "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/processor/percentprivilegedtime",
            "type": "builtin",
            "unit": "Percent"
        },
        {
            "annotation": [
                {
                    "displayName": "Memory available",
                    "locale": "en-us"
                }
            ],
            "class": "memory",
            "counter": "availablememory",
            "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/memory/availablememory",
            "type": "builtin",
            "unit": "Bytes"
        },
        {
            "annotation": [
                {
                    "displayName": "Swap percent used",
                    "locale": "en-us"
                }
            ],
            "class": "memory",
            "counter": "percentusedswap",
            "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/memory/percentusedswap",
            "type": "builtin",
            "unit": "Percent"
        },
        {
            "annotation": [
                {
                    "displayName": "Memory used",
                    "locale": "en-us"
                }
            ],
            "class": "memory",
            "counter": "usedmemory",
            "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/memory/usedmemory",
            "type": "builtin",
            "unit": "Bytes"
        },
        {
            "annotation": [
                {
                    "displayName": "Page reads",
                    "locale": "en-us"
                }
            ],
            "class": "memory",
            "counter": "pagesreadpersec",
            "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/memory/pagesreadpersec",
            "type": "builtin",
            "unit": "CountPerSecond"
        },
        {
            "annotation": [
                {
                    "displayName": "Swap available",
                    "locale": "en-us"
                }
            ],
            "class": "memory",
            "counter": "availableswap",
            "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/memory/availableswap",
            "type": "builtin",
            "unit": "Bytes"
        },
        {
            "annotation": [
                {
                    "displayName": "Swap percent available",
                    "locale": "en-us"
                }
            ],
            "class": "memory",
            "counter": "percentavailableswap",
            "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/memory/percentavailableswap",
            "type": "builtin",
            "unit": "Percent"
        },
        {
            "annotation": [
                {
                    "displayName": "Mem. percent available",
                    "locale": "en-us"
                }
            ],
            "class": "memory",
            "counter": "percentavailablememory",
            "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/memory/percentavailablememory",
            "type": "builtin",
            "unit": "Percent"
        },
        {
            "annotation": [
                {
                    "displayName": "Pages",
                    "locale": "en-us"
                }
            ],
            "class": "memory",
            "counter": "pagespersec",
            "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/memory/pagespersec",
            "type": "builtin",
            "unit": "CountPerSecond"
        },
        {
            "annotation": [
                {
                    "displayName": "Swap used",
                    "locale": "en-us"
                }
            ],
            "class": "memory",
            "counter": "usedswap",
            "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/memory/usedswap",
            "type": "builtin",
            "unit": "Bytes"
        },
        {
            "annotation": [
                {
                    "displayName": "Memory percentage",
                    "locale": "en-us"
                }
            ],
            "class": "memory",
            "counter": "percentusedmemory",
            "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/memory/percentusedmemory",
            "type": "builtin",
            "unit": "Percent"
        },
        {
            "annotation": [
                {
                    "displayName": "Page writes",
                    "locale": "en-us"
                }
            ],
            "class": "memory",
            "counter": "pageswrittenpersec",
            "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/memory/pageswrittenpersec",
            "type": "builtin",
            "unit": "CountPerSecond"
        }
    ]
}
```

azure_extension_diagnostics_linux_syslogevents.json

```
{
    "syslogEventConfiguration": {
        "LOG_AUTH": "LOG_DEBUG",
        "LOG_AUTHPRIV": "LOG_DEBUG",
        "LOG_CRON": "LOG_DEBUG",
        "LOG_DAEMON": "LOG_DEBUG",
        "LOG_FTP": "LOG_DEBUG",
        "LOG_KERN": "LOG_DEBUG",
        "LOG_LOCAL0": "LOG_DEBUG",
        "LOG_LOCAL1": "LOG_DEBUG",
        "LOG_LOCAL2": "LOG_DEBUG",
        "LOG_LOCAL3": "LOG_DEBUG",
        "LOG_LOCAL4": "LOG_DEBUG",
        "LOG_LOCAL5": "LOG_DEBUG",
        "LOG_LOCAL6": "LOG_DEBUG",
        "LOG_LOCAL7": "LOG_DEBUG",
        "LOG_LPR": "LOG_DEBUG",
        "LOG_MAIL": "LOG_DEBUG",
        "LOG_NEWS": "LOG_DEBUG",
        "LOG_SYSLOG": "LOG_DEBUG",
        "LOG_USER": "LOG_DEBUG",
        "LOG_UUCP": "LOG_DEBUG"
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Ready to go module if needed:
https://github.com/elongstreet88/terraform-linuxdiagnostic-agent-module

Comment: Hi, Were you able to solve your problem? Please mark it as answer so that it can be helpful to others also. Thanks!

Comment: nice module! useful - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AS pointed out above you need to add sas token for storage account, output this storage account SAS token using terraform an then input this in the protected settings that way ( I will copy-past my full config to help.... ) :

```
                resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "nva1_diag_setting" {
                 name                 = "${var.current-name-convention-core-module}-nva1-ub16-LinuxDiagnostics"
                 virtual_machine_id = "${azurerm_virtual_machine.nva1-ub16.id}"
                 publisher                     = "Microsoft.Azure.Diagnostics"
                 type                          = "LinuxDiagnostic"
                 type_handler_version          = "3.0"
                 auto_upgrade_minor_version    = "true"

                  settings = <<SETTINGS
                        {
                        "StorageAccount": "${var.stor-log-repo-name}",
                        "ladCfg": {
                            "diagnosticMonitorConfiguration": {
                            "eventVolume": "Medium", 
                            "metrics": {
                                "metricAggregation": [
                                {
                                    "scheduledTransferPeriod": "PT1H"
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "scheduledTransferPeriod": "PT1M"
                                }
                                ], 
                                "resourceId": "${azurerm_virtual_machine.nva1-ub16.id}"
                            }, 
                            "performanceCounters": {
                                "performanceCounterConfiguration": [
                                {
                                    "annotation": [
                                    {
                                        "displayName": "Disk read guest OS", 
                                        "locale": "en-us"
                                    }
                                    ], 
                                    "class": "disk", 
                                    "condition": "IsAggregate=TRUE", 
                                    "counter": "readbytespersecond", 
                                    "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/disk/readbytespersecond", 
                                    "type": "builtin", 
                                    "unit": "BytesPerSecond"
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "annotation": [
                                    {
                                        "displayName": "Disk writes", 
                                        "locale": "en-us"
                                    }
                                    ], 
                                    "class": "disk", 
                                    "condition": "IsAggregate=TRUE", 
                                    "counter": "writespersecond", 
                                    "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/disk/writespersecond", 
                                    "type": "builtin", 
                                    "unit": "CountPerSecond"
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "annotation": [
                                    {
                                        "displayName": "Disk transfer time", 
                                        "locale": "en-us"
                                    }
                                    ], 
                                    "class": "disk", 
                                    "condition": "IsAggregate=TRUE", 
                                    "counter": "averagetransfertime", 
                                    "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/disk/averagetransfertime", 
                                    "type": "builtin", 
                                    "unit": "Seconds"
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "annotation": [
                                    {
                                        "displayName": "Disk transfers", 
                                        "locale": "en-us"
                                    }
                                    ], 
                                    "class": "disk", 
                                    "condition": "IsAggregate=TRUE", 
                                    "counter": "transferspersecond", 
                                    "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/disk/transferspersecond", 
                                    "type": "builtin", 
                                    "unit": "CountPerSecond"
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "annotation": [
                                    {
                                        "displayName": "Disk write guest OS", 
                                        "locale": "en-us"
                                    }
                                    ], 
                                    "class": "disk", 
                                    "condition": "IsAggregate=TRUE", 
                                    "counter": "writebytespersecond", 
                                    "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/disk/writebytespersecond", 
                                    "type": "builtin", 
                                    "unit": "BytesPerSecond"
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "annotation": [
                                    {
                                        "displayName": "Disk read time", 
                                        "locale": "en-us"
                                    }
                                    ], 
                                    "class": "disk", 
                                    "condition": "IsAggregate=TRUE", 
                                    "counter": "averagereadtime", 
                                    "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/disk/averagereadtime", 
                                    "type": "builtin", 
                                    "unit": "Seconds"
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "annotation": [
                                    {
                                        "displayName": "Disk write time", 
                                        "locale": "en-us"
                                    }
                                    ], 
                                    "class": "disk", 
                                    "condition": "IsAggregate=TRUE", 
                                    "counter": "averagewritetime", 
                                    "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/disk/averagewritetime", 
                                    "type": "builtin", 
                                    "unit": "Seconds"
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "annotation": [
                                    {
                                        "displayName": "Disk total bytes", 
                                        "locale": "en-us"
                                    }
                                    ], 
                                    "class": "disk", 
                                    "condition": "IsAggregate=TRUE", 
                                    "counter": "bytespersecond", 
                                    "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/disk/bytespersecond", 
                                    "type": "builtin", 
                                    "unit": "BytesPerSecond"
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "annotation": [
                                    {
                                        "displayName": "Disk reads", 
                                        "locale": "en-us"
                                    }
                                    ], 
                                    "class": "disk", 
                                    "condition": "IsAggregate=TRUE", 
                                    "counter": "readspersecond", 
                                    "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/disk/readspersecond", 
                                    "type": "builtin", 
                                    "unit": "CountPerSecond"
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "annotation": [
                                    {
                                        "displayName": "Disk queue length", 
                                        "locale": "en-us"
                                    }
                                    ], 
                                    "class": "disk", 
                                    "condition": "IsAggregate=TRUE", 
                                    "counter": "averagediskqueuelength", 
                                    "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/disk/averagediskqueuelength", 
                                    "type": "builtin", 
                                    "unit": "Count"
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "annotation": [
                                    {
                                        "displayName": "Network in guest OS", 
                                        "locale": "en-us"
                                    }
                                    ], 
                                    "class": "network", 
                                    "counter": "bytesreceived", 
                                    "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/network/bytesreceived", 
                                    "type": "builtin", 
                                    "unit": "Bytes"
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "annotation": [
                                    {
                                        "displayName": "Network total bytes", 
                                        "locale": "en-us"
                                    }
                                    ], 
                                    "class": "network", 
                                    "counter": "bytestotal", 
                                    "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/network/bytestotal", 
                                    "type": "builtin", 
                                    "unit": "Bytes"
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "annotation": [
                                    {
                                        "displayName": "Network out guest OS", 
                                        "locale": "en-us"
                                    }
                                    ], 
                                    "class": "network", 
                                    "counter": "bytestransmitted", 
                                    "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/network/bytestransmitted", 
                                    "type": "builtin", 
                                    "unit": "Bytes"
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "annotation": [
                                    {
                                        "displayName": "Network collisions", 
                                        "locale": "en-us"
                                    }
                                    ], 
                                    "class": "network", 
                                    "counter": "totalcollisions", 
                                    "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/network/totalcollisions", 
                                    "type": "builtin", 
                                    "unit": "Count"
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "annotation": [
                                    {
                                        "displayName": "Packets received errors", 
                                        "locale": "en-us"
                                    }
                                    ], 
                                    "class": "network", 
                                    "counter": "totalrxerrors", 
                                    "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/network/totalrxerrors", 
                                    "type": "builtin", 
                                    "unit": "Count"
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "annotation": [
                                    {
                                        "displayName": "Packets sent", 
                                        "locale": "en-us"
                                    }
                                    ], 
                                    "class": "network", 
                                    "counter": "packetstransmitted", 
                                    "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/network/packetstransmitted", 
                                    "type": "builtin", 
                                    "unit": "Count"
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "annotation": [
                                    {
                                        "displayName": "Packets received", 
                                        "locale": "en-us"
                                    }
                                    ], 
                                    "class": "network", 
                                    "counter": "packetsreceived", 
                                    "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/network/packetsreceived", 
                                    "type": "builtin", 
                                    "unit": "Count"
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "annotation": [
                                    {
                                        "displayName": "Packets sent errors", 
                                        "locale": "en-us"
                                    }
                                    ], 
                                    "class": "network", 
                                    "counter": "totaltxerrors", 
                                    "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/network/totaltxerrors", 
                                    "type": "builtin", 
                                    "unit": "Count"
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "annotation": [
                                    {
                                        "displayName": "Filesystem transfers/sec", 
                                        "locale": "en-us"
                                    }
                                    ], 
                                    "class": "filesystem", 
                                    "condition": "IsAggregate=TRUE", 
                                    "counter": "transferspersecond", 
                                    "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/filesystem/transferspersecond", 
                                    "type": "builtin", 
                                    "unit": "CountPerSecond"
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "annotation": [
                                    {
                                        "displayName": "Filesystem % free space", 
                                        "locale": "en-us"
                                    }
                                    ], 
                                    "class": "filesystem", 
                                    "condition": "IsAggregate=TRUE", 
                                    "counter": "percentfreespace", 
                                    "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/filesystem/percentfreespace", 
                                    "type": "builtin", 
                                    "unit": "Percent"
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "annotation": [
                                    {
                                        "displayName": "Filesystem % used space", 
                                        "locale": "en-us"
                                    }
                                    ], 
                                    "class": "filesystem", 
                                    "condition": "IsAggregate=TRUE", 
                                    "counter": "percentusedspace", 
                                    "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/filesystem/percentusedspace", 
                                    "type": "builtin", 
                                    "unit": "Percent"
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "annotation": [
                                    {
                                        "displayName": "Filesystem used space", 
                                        "locale": "en-us"
                                    }
                                    ], 
                                    "class": "filesystem", 
                                    "condition": "IsAggregate=TRUE", 
                                    "counter": "usedspace", 
                                    "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/filesystem/usedspace", 
                                    "type": "builtin", 
                                    "unit": "Bytes"
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "annotation": [
                                    {
                                        "displayName": "Filesystem read bytes/sec", 
                                        "locale": "en-us"
                                    }
                                    ], 
                                    "class": "filesystem", 
                                    "condition": "IsAggregate=TRUE", 
                                    "counter": "bytesreadpersecond", 
                                    "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/filesystem/bytesreadpersecond", 
                                    "type": "builtin", 
                                    "unit": "CountPerSecond"
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "annotation": [
                                    {
                                        "displayName": "Filesystem free space", 
                                        "locale": "en-us"
                                    }
                                    ], 
                                    "class": "filesystem", 
                                    "condition": "IsAggregate=TRUE", 
                                    "counter": "freespace", 
                                    "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/filesystem/freespace", 
                                    "type": "builtin", 
                                    "unit": "Bytes"
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "annotation": [
                                    {
                                        "displayName": "Filesystem % free inodes", 
                                        "locale": "en-us"
                                    }
                                    ], 
                                    "class": "filesystem", 
                                    "condition": "IsAggregate=TRUE", 
                                    "counter": "percentfreeinodes", 
                                    "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/filesystem/percentfreeinodes", 
                                    "type": "builtin", 
                                    "unit": "Percent"
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "annotation": [
                                    {
                                        "displayName": "Filesystem bytes/sec", 
                                        "locale": "en-us"
                                    }
                                    ], 
                                    "class": "filesystem", 
                                    "condition": "IsAggregate=TRUE", 
                                    "counter": "bytespersecond", 
                                    "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/filesystem/bytespersecond", 
                                    "type": "builtin", 
                                    "unit": "BytesPerSecond"
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "annotation": [
                                    {
                                        "displayName": "Filesystem reads/sec", 
                                        "locale": "en-us"
                                    }
                                    ], 
                                    "class": "filesystem", 
                                    "condition": "IsAggregate=TRUE", 
                                    "counter": "readspersecond", 
                                    "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/filesystem/readspersecond", 
                                    "type": "builtin", 
                                    "unit": "CountPerSecond"
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "annotation": [
                                    {
                                        "displayName": "Filesystem write bytes/sec", 
                                        "locale": "en-us"
                                    }
                                    ], 
                                    "class": "filesystem", 
                                    "condition": "IsAggregate=TRUE", 
                                    "counter": "byteswrittenpersecond", 
                                    "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/filesystem/byteswrittenpersecond", 
                                    "type": "builtin", 
                                    "unit": "CountPerSecond"
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "annotation": [
                                    {
                                        "displayName": "Filesystem writes/sec", 
                                        "locale": "en-us"
                                    }
                                    ], 
                                    "class": "filesystem", 
                                    "condition": "IsAggregate=TRUE", 
                                    "counter": "writespersecond", 
                                    "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/filesystem/writespersecond", 
                                    "type": "builtin", 
                                    "unit": "CountPerSecond"
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "annotation": [
                                    {
                                        "displayName": "Filesystem % used inodes", 
                                        "locale": "en-us"
                                    }
                                    ], 
                                    "class": "filesystem", 
                                    "condition": "IsAggregate=TRUE", 
                                    "counter": "percentusedinodes", 
                                    "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/filesystem/percentusedinodes", 
                                    "type": "builtin", 
                                    "unit": "Percent"
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "annotation": [
                                    {
                                        "displayName": "CPU IO wait time", 
                                        "locale": "en-us"
                                    }
                                    ], 
                                    "class": "processor", 
                                    "condition": "IsAggregate=TRUE", 
                                    "counter": "percentiowaittime", 
                                    "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/processor/percentiowaittime", 
                                    "type": "builtin", 
                                    "unit": "Percent"
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "annotation": [
                                    {
                                        "displayName": "CPU user time", 
                                        "locale": "en-us"
                                    }
                                    ], 
                                    "class": "processor", 
                                    "condition": "IsAggregate=TRUE", 
                                    "counter": "percentusertime", 
                                    "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/processor/percentusertime", 
                                    "type": "builtin", 
                                    "unit": "Percent"
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "annotation": [
                                    {
                                        "displayName": "CPU nice time", 
                                        "locale": "en-us"
                                    }
                                    ], 
                                    "class": "processor", 
                                    "condition": "IsAggregate=TRUE", 
                                    "counter": "percentnicetime", 
                                    "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/processor/percentnicetime", 
                                    "type": "builtin", 
                                    "unit": "Percent"
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "annotation": [
                                    {
                                        "displayName": "CPU percentage guest OS", 
                                        "locale": "en-us"
                                    }
                                    ], 
                                    "class": "processor", 
                                    "condition": "IsAggregate=TRUE", 
                                    "counter": "percentprocessortime", 
                                    "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/processor/percentprocessortime", 
                                    "type": "builtin", 
                                    "unit": "Percent"
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "annotation": [
                                    {
                                        "displayName": "CPU interrupt time", 
                                        "locale": "en-us"
                                    }
                                    ], 
                                    "class": "processor", 
                                    "condition": "IsAggregate=TRUE", 
                                    "counter": "percentinterrupttime", 
                                    "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/processor/percentinterrupttime", 
                                    "type": "builtin", 
                                    "unit": "Percent"
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "annotation": [
                                    {
                                        "displayName": "CPU idle time", 
                                        "locale": "en-us"
                                    }
                                    ], 
                                    "class": "processor", 
                                    "condition": "IsAggregate=TRUE", 
                                    "counter": "percentidletime", 
                                    "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/processor/percentidletime", 
                                    "type": "builtin", 
                                    "unit": "Percent"
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "annotation": [
                                    {
                                        "displayName": "CPU privileged time", 
                                        "locale": "en-us"
                                    }
                                    ], 
                                    "class": "processor", 
                                    "condition": "IsAggregate=TRUE", 
                                    "counter": "percentprivilegedtime", 
                                    "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/processor/percentprivilegedtime", 
                                    "type": "builtin", 
                                    "unit": "Percent"
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "annotation": [
                                    {
                                        "displayName": "Memory available", 
                                        "locale": "en-us"
                                    }
                                    ], 
                                    "class": "memory", 
                                    "counter": "availablememory", 
                                    "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/memory/availablememory", 
                                    "type": "builtin", 
                                    "unit": "Bytes"
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "annotation": [
                                    {
                                        "displayName": "Swap percent used", 
                                        "locale": "en-us"
                                    }
                                    ], 
                                    "class": "memory", 
                                    "counter": "percentusedswap", 
                                    "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/memory/percentusedswap", 
                                    "type": "builtin", 
                                    "unit": "Percent"
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "annotation": [
                                    {
                                        "displayName": "Memory used", 
                                        "locale": "en-us"
                                    }
                                    ], 
                                    "class": "memory", 
                                    "counter": "usedmemory", 
                                    "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/memory/usedmemory", 
                                    "type": "builtin", 
                                    "unit": "Bytes"
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "annotation": [
                                    {
                                        "displayName": "Page reads", 
                                        "locale": "en-us"
                                    }
                                    ], 
                                    "class": "memory", 
                                    "counter": "pagesreadpersec", 
                                    "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/memory/pagesreadpersec", 
                                    "type": "builtin", 
                                    "unit": "CountPerSecond"
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "annotation": [
                                    {
                                        "displayName": "Swap available", 
                                        "locale": "en-us"
                                    }
                                    ], 
                                    "class": "memory", 
                                    "counter": "availableswap", 
                                    "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/memory/availableswap", 
                                    "type": "builtin", 
                                    "unit": "Bytes"
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "annotation": [
                                    {
                                        "displayName": "Swap percent available", 
                                        "locale": "en-us"
                                    }
                                    ], 
                                    "class": "memory", 
                                    "counter": "percentavailableswap", 
                                    "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/memory/percentavailableswap", 
                                    "type": "builtin", 
                                    "unit": "Percent"
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "annotation": [
                                    {
                                        "displayName": "Mem. percent available", 
                                        "locale": "en-us"
                                    }
                                    ], 
                                    "class": "memory", 
                                    "counter": "percentavailablememory", 
                                    "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/memory/percentavailablememory", 
                                    "type": "builtin", 
                                    "unit": "Percent"
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "annotation": [
                                    {
                                        "displayName": "Pages", 
                                        "locale": "en-us"
                                    }
                                    ], 
                                    "class": "memory", 
                                    "counter": "pagespersec", 
                                    "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/memory/pagespersec", 
                                    "type": "builtin", 
                                    "unit": "CountPerSecond"
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "annotation": [
                                    {
                                        "displayName": "Swap used", 
                                        "locale": "en-us"
                                    }
                                    ], 
                                    "class": "memory", 
                                    "counter": "usedswap", 
                                    "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/memory/usedswap", 
                                    "type": "builtin", 
                                    "unit": "Bytes"
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "annotation": [
                                    {
                                        "displayName": "Memory percentage", 
                                        "locale": "en-us"
                                    }
                                    ], 
                                    "class": "memory", 
                                    "counter": "percentusedmemory", 
                                    "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/memory/percentusedmemory", 
                                    "type": "builtin", 
                                    "unit": "Percent"
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "annotation": [
                                    {
                                        "displayName": "Page writes", 
                                        "locale": "en-us"
                                    }
                                    ], 
                                    "class": "memory", 
                                    "counter": "pageswrittenpersec", 
                                    "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/memory/pageswrittenpersec", 
                                    "type": "builtin", 
                                    "unit": "CountPerSecond"
                                }
                                ]
                            }, 
                            "syslogEvents": {
                                "syslogEventConfiguration": {
                                "LOG_AUTH": "LOG_DEBUG", 
                                "LOG_AUTHPRIV": "LOG_DEBUG", 
                                "LOG_CRON": "LOG_DEBUG", 
                                "LOG_DAEMON": "LOG_DEBUG", 
                                "LOG_FTP": "LOG_DEBUG", 
                                "LOG_KERN": "LOG_DEBUG", 
                                "LOG_LOCAL0": "LOG_DEBUG", 
                                "LOG_LOCAL1": "LOG_DEBUG", 
                                "LOG_LOCAL2": "LOG_DEBUG", 
                                "LOG_LOCAL3": "LOG_DEBUG", 
                                "LOG_LOCAL4": "LOG_DEBUG", 
                                "LOG_LOCAL5": "LOG_DEBUG", 
                                "LOG_LOCAL6": "LOG_DEBUG", 
                                "LOG_LOCAL7": "LOG_DEBUG", 
                                "LOG_LPR": "LOG_DEBUG", 
                                "LOG_MAIL": "LOG_DEBUG", 
                                "LOG_NEWS": "LOG_DEBUG", 
                                "LOG_SYSLOG": "LOG_DEBUG", 
                                "LOG_USER": "LOG_DEBUG", 
                                "LOG_UUCP": "LOG_DEBUG"
                                }
                            }
                            }, 
                            "sampleRateInSeconds": 15
                        }
                        }


                SETTINGS

                  protected_settings = <<PROTECTED_SETTINGS
                {
                  "storageAccountName": "${var.stor-log-repo-name}",
                  "storageAccountSasToken": "${var.stor-log-repo-sas}",
                  "sinksConfig": 
                      {
                        "sink": [
                          {
                              "name": "SyslogJsonBlob",
                              "type": "JsonBlob"
                          },
                          {
                              "name": "LinuxCpuJsonBlob",
                              "type": "JsonBlob"
                          }
                        ]
                  }
                }


                PROTECTED_SETTINGS
                }
```

Then you will have this kind of data in your storage account :

[image]

As we speak, Terraform does not support SAS token ( yet ) for Azure EVent hub ( only for azure storage for now ) , so we cannot use terraform to do that, I opened a github [issue](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/7160), let's see if this is going to be added.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response. This worked perfectly! Updating to use SAS was part of it, but apparently the json syntax is touchy. I will post my full example for others who need help getting the SAS token.

Comment: Yeah, it worth share since it is takeing some time to sort out the json synthax

Answer (score 1):

According to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/diagnostics-linux#protected-settings), you need to specify **storageAccountSasToken** not storageAccountKey for the Linux Diagnostic Extension.

Your Protected Settings should be like this:

```
    protected_settings = <<PROTECTED_SETTINGS
    {
        "storageAccountName": "YOUR_ACCOUNT_NAME",
        "storageAccountSasToken": "YOUR SAS TOKEN"
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This definitely helped, but Mouldri's response must have fixed some other json issues i was having. Thanks for the assist.